# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property not initialized

Tags: c#, sql, .net

How do i resolve ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property is not initialized. I already made my cmd.Connection = con;  this is my code please help

```
Private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (img_file != null)
    { 

FileStream fs = new FileStream(img_file, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        byte[]image = new byte[fs.Length];

        fs.Read(image,0,Convert.ToString(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member_details (name,address,email,phone_number,picture) VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+"', '"+textBox2.Text+"', '"+textBox3.Text+"', @pic)", con);
        SqlParameter prm = new SqlParameter("@pic", SqlDbType.VarBinary, image.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0,0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, image);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Format the code and post it

Comment: Two things, Where are you initializing the connection object "con" and second one, you don't need to set cmd.Connection= con as you are already passing it as paramater to SqlCommand constructor during it's initilization

Comment: @Sujith: one more, beware of sqlInjection

Comment: @un-lucky yup. Instead of adding the textbox values directly to the query, parameterize the query or use SP with paramters

Comment: @Sujith I want to initialize it to SqlCommand

Comment: @Pils Can you refer to this msdn link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx . It has got what you need with proper examples. Would be helpful to you. Also read something on SQLInjection and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code as reference to fix your code:

```
string connetionString = null;
SqlConnection cnn ;
SqlCommand cmd ;
string sql = null;

connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
sql = "Your SQL Statemnt Here";

cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
try
{
    cnn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
    cnn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show (" ExecuteNonQuery in SqlCommand executed !!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
}
```

You can simply initialize and close connections by

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
--write all your command n execution code here---;
}
```

Apart from this, one suggestion, you need to use parameterized query or Stored Proc with paramerts to avoid SQLInjection:

Reference to SQLInjection : https://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection